# Where to set wait cursor in long operation in MVP pattern?

Tags: mvp, long-integer

For a long operation that will be executed in presenter, where to set the wait cursor?

1. in View? the view shouldn't know too much about business logic, it is passive.
2. in presenter? seems odd in presenter to call UI code.
3. add method  to View interface, like SetWait(bool), and call it in presenter?

So what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it as no.3 from the presenter tell the view to show the user a "long running operation" feedback... whatever that means for the view (wait cursor, message, etc.)